# Using zip file in html

Tags: leaflet

I have my map files vdcar.js (about 27.79 MB) and vdcar.js.zip (about 9.79 MB) in same folder in server. Also have TestPopden.html (http://ngiip.gov.np/THEMATIC_MAPS/TestPopden.html) and .htaccess (empty file) in same location. I found that it takes maximum time (more than 30 minutes) to open the unzipped map file.

What I need to do (with TestPopden.html and .htaccess files) to use zipped version of my map file?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Population Density</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.2&sensor=false"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="leaflet.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="POPCEN/Popcen.css" />
  <script src="leaflet.js"></script>
  <script src="leaflet-google.js"></script>
  <script src="leaflet.groupedlayercontrol.js"></script>
  <script src="COMMON/nepalar.js"></script>
  <script src="ADMINISTRATIVE/vdcar.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
   <div id="map" style="position: absolute; top: 5; bottom: 5; left: 5;
            right: 5; z-index: 9999; width: 99%; height: 98%">
      </div>
  <script>
    var map = L.map('map', {zoomControl: false, maxZoom: 12}).setView([28.1,84.1], 7);
      new L.Control.Zoom({ position: 'bottomright' }).addTo(map);
      var noneAttrib='Nepal Map &copy <a href="http://www.dos.gov.np/" target="_blank">Survey Department</a>, Census Data &copy <a  href="http://www.cbs.gov.np/" target="_blank">CBS</a>, Nepal';
      var none = new L.tileLayer('', {attribution: noneAttrib});
      var googleAttrib='Reference Map Data &copy; <a href="http://google.org">GoogleRoadMap</a>';
      none.addTo(map);

    var infonep = L.control({position: 'bottomleft'});
    infonep.onAdd = function (map) {
        this._div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'infonep'); // create a div with a class "infonep"
       this.update();
        return this._div;
    };

    infonep.update = function (props) {
        this._div.innerHTML = '<h4>Nepal Population Information:</h4>' + '<hr>' +  (props ?
          '<b>' + 'NEPAL' + '</b>'
             +  '<br/>' + 'Population: ' + props.POP68 + '</b>'
             +  '<br/>' + 'Male Population: ' + props.MALE68 + '</b>'
           +  '<br/>' + 'Female Population: ' + props.FEMALE68 + '</b>'
             +  '<br/>' + 'Area (Sq. Km.): ' + props.AREA_SQKM + '</b>'
           +  '<br/>' + '<b>' + 'Population Density: ' + props.POPDEN68 + ' people / Sq.Km.<sup>2</sup>' + '</b>'
            : 'Move mouse over the country');
    };
    infonep.addTo(map);
   function getColor(d) {
        return d > 1000  ? '#662506' :
             d > 800  ? '#993404' :
              d > 600  ? '#CC4C02' :
             d > 400  ? '#EC7014' :
             d > 200   ? '#FE9929' :
            d > 100   ? '#FEC44F' :
            d > 50   ? '#FEE391' :
                          '#FFFFE5';
    }

    function stylenep(feature) {
        return {
            fillColor: getColor(feature.properties.POPDEN68),
           weight: 1,
           opacity: 1,
         color: 'white',
            dashArray: '2',
            fillOpacity: 0.7
        };
 }

        var popNep = new L.geoJson(nepalar, {
            style: stylenep,
           onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
           var defaultStyle = layer.style,
               that = this;//NEW
          layer.on('mouseover', function (e) {
              this.setStyle({
              weight: 3,
             color: '#666',
                dashArray: '',
                fillOpacity: 0.7
              });
                infonep.update(layer.feature.properties);
          });
            layer.on('mouseout', function (e) {
              popNep.resetStyle(e.target); //NEW
                infonep.update();
          });
            }
          });
            map.addLayer(popNep);

    function stylevdc(feature) {
        return {
          fillColor: 'transparent',
           weight: 0.1,
           opacity: 1,
         color: '#000000',
         fillOpacity: 0.7
      };
   }

       var popVdc = L.geoJson(vdcar, {
            style: stylevdc,
              onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                layer.bindPopup("Zone:  " + feature.properties.ZNAME
               + '<br>' + "District:  " + feature.properties.DNAME
               + '<br>' + "VDC:  " + feature.properties.GAZETTE);
             }
           });

     var googleLayer = new L.Google('ROADMAP', {attribution: googleAttrib + ' ' + noneAttrib});
     var none   = new L.tileLayer('', {attribution: noneAttrib});
     var baseMaps = {
      "Google Base Map": googleLayer,
      "Turn Off Base Map": none,
     };

    var groupedOverlays = {
        "AdminDivisions": {
         "Nepal Population": popNep,
         "VDCs(Click to display name)": popVdc
      }
     };

     L.control.groupedLayers(baseMaps, groupedOverlays, {collapsed: false}).addTo(map);

    map.on ('overlayadd', function (eventLayer) {
     if (eventLayer.name === 'Nepal Population') {
         infonep.addTo(map);
     } else if (eventLayer.name === 'VDCs(Click to display name)') {
             map.addLayer(popVdc);
      } else {
     }
    });
    map.on ('overlayremove', function (eventLayer) {
      if (eventLayer.name === 'Nepal Population') {
         map.removeControl(infonep);
      } else if (eventLayer.name === 'VDCs(Click to display name)') {
             map.removeLayer(popVdc);
    } else {
    }
    });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Zipping a file will not help you at all. You're experiencing problems because you have too much data, you can't load everything at once.

Comment: But, Jakub, data representing a map is normally big in size. I hope there is some way out to use compressed version of the data.

Comment: You seriously can't expect a 30 Mb GeoJSON file to be usable in the Browser. You need to rethink of how you could show the same data in a different way.

Comment: Well, can I use gzip compressed file to overcome this problem? If so, what should I do?

Comment: It's not the size in Mb that's the problem. It's the size of data, number of features you try to display. You need a server to show just the data in the current view or to show the data with less details.

Comment: you may be looking for something like this https://github.com/nrenner/mapsplit-map, but this only works with osm.pbf files.

Comment: Can you simplify the geometry using something like [mapshaper](http://www.mapshaper.org/)?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered with exactly the same problem while displaying VDC layer for nepal. The concept i came up with is to create tiles using [tilemill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/) (since the vdc layers are static and the data is updated once in a month (at max in my case)) extracted using [mb-util](https://github.com/mapbox/mbutil) and served using apache/iis (both work fine). Although the files created were about 100 mb in my case, but greatly depends on the zoom levels that you create the tiles for. Here is my result (takes less than a second to load in my local server) see the result below with the data transfer:
[image: Result of tilemill and leaflet]